# Action bar tab tab width not fixed

Tags: android, mono

my application contains action bar tab with fragments. it will add dynamically tabs to action bar. when multiple tabs added the text on tab gets wrapped. is there any way to set text in single line only

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this very useful library to work with ActionBar Tabs in android:
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Hope it helps you! ;)